# name for the trick of alternately swapping inner and outer optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, terminology

With a (possibly non-convex) function $f(a,b)$
and an objective 
$$
\min_{a,b} f(a,b) = \min_a \min_b f(a,b) = \min_b \min_a f(a,b)
$$
one can achieve a nonincreasing solution path by iteratively solving the  inner problems 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
a_{t+1} = \argmin_a f(a,b_{t}) \\
b_{t+1} = \argmin_b f(a_{t},b)
$$

I've repeatedly found it helpful in max-likelihood or MAP problems and would like to be able to talk about the approach in shorthand.

***Is there a name for this class of techniques?***

I've been calling it "alternating directions" but that is not 100% right ; or "swapping inner optimizations" which is descriptive but I'm not sure that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent).

Comment: In this case, the name of the method is a complete answer, and the link is only for additional reading.